# Spark Java: Escape dot in column names for vector assembler

Tags: java, apache-spark, vector, escaping, dot

I have a Dataset where some column names have dots. The problem arises when it comes to Vector Assembler. It seems that they do not get along, so I tried to escape the dots in many ways but nothing changed.

```
String[] expincols = newfilenameavgpeaks.columns();

VectorAssembler assemblerexp = new VectorAssembler()
                    .setInputCols(expincols)
                    .setOutputCol("intensity");

Dataset<Row> filenameoutput = assemblerexp.transform(newfilenameavgpeaks);
```

I have wrapped every element in expincols with: "`", "``","```","````","'",'"', etc but nothing! I also tried these in the column names of newfilenameavgpeaks but still nothing. Any ideas how to escape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dataset contains a column `a.b` you can still use `` df.col(`a.b`) `` to select a column with a `.` in its name. This works because [Dataset.col](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4b84e571f06dec953d532e60942b0e96b4100abe/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L1346) tries to [resolve](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4b84e571f06dec953d532e60942b0e96b4100abe/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L260) the column name and can handle the backticks.

[VectorAssembler.transform](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4b84e571f06dec953d532e60942b0e96b4100abe/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/VectorAssembler.scala#L84) however takes the schema of the supplied dataset and uses this [StructType](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4b84e571f06dec953d532e60942b0e96b4100abe/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.scala#L102) to handle the column names in [VectorAssembler.transformSchema](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4b84e571f06dec953d532e60942b0e96b4100abe/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/VectorAssembler.scala#L157). The [apply method of StructType](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4b84e571f06dec953d532e60942b0e96b4100abe/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.scala#L275) simply does not contain the logic to handle the backticks and throws an `IllegalArgumentException` if the column names do not match exactly.

Therefore the only option is to rename the columns before supplying them to the VectorAssembler:

```java
Dataset<Row> newfilenameavgpeaks = ...

for( String col : newfilenameavgpeaks.columns()) {
    newfilenameavgpeaks = newfilenameavgpeaks
            .withColumnRenamed(col, col.replace('.', '_'));
}

VectorAssembler assemblerexp = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(newfilenameavgpeaks.columns()).setOutputCol("intensity");

Dataset<Row> filenameoutput = assemblerexp.transform(newfilenameavgpeaks);
```